# How to change my sql query so it remove rows with certain values in column

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse

I have a sql query:

```
SELECT
  id, value, count(value) as count
FROM my.data.base
GROUP BY id, value
```

It brings me this table:

```
ID       value    count
1       upload     12
1       change     24
1       reset      5
2       upload     11
2       reset      8
```

Now, I want to remove from processing (counting) all "values" equal to "reset". So my result must look like this:

```
ID       value    count
1       upload     12
1       change     24
2       upload     11
```

How could i specify it IN MY QUERY? This didn't work:

```
SELECT
  id, value, count(value) as count
FROM my.data.base
WHERE value != "reset"
GROUP BY id, value
```

Comment: Your query should work. Can you please show the output of your last query?

Answer (score 1):

You should use single quotes.

```
SELECT
  id, value, count(value) as count
FROM my.data.base
WHERE value != 'reset'
GROUP BY id, value
```